# Как осуществить заполнение списка с клавиаутуры?

Tags: c#, list

```
static void Main(string[] args)

        {
        Menu:
            List<string> Cars = new List<string>();
            Cars.Add(new string("Сузуки "));
            Cars.Add(new string("Мазда "));
            
            Console.WriteLine("Машина: ");
            string add = Console.ReadLine();
            Cars.Add(add);
            Console.Write("Вы ввели:");
            Cars.ForEach(Console.Write);

            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
            goto Menu;
         }
```

Но, при выводе списка, вводимое значение каждый раз "забывается". Как заставить список нормально записывать в себя вводимые данные?

Comment: Прочитайте ваш код, вот прям пошагово, что видите? Я помогу: `Создать новую коллекцию Cars` > `Добавить туда новую строку из строки` (х2) > `Вывести на экран "Машина"` > `Спросить строку у пользователя` > `Добавить полученное в коллекцию` > `Вывести на экран "Вы ввели"` > `Пройтись циклом foreach по коллекции с выводом на экран` > `Ждать нажатие кнопки` > `Очистить консоль` > `Повторить`. Вот прочитайте это внимательно, максимально внимательно и вникните в эти действия, а затем задайте себе вопрос "почему постоянно новые"?

Comment: У вас ничего не забывается и все прекрасно выводится, но с каждой итерацией цикла у вас коллекция обнуляется. Программа делает ровно то, что вы и написали. Еще не используйте goto, а вместо этого while(true) например.

Comment: твою дивизию, обидно чувствовать себя тупым

Comment: спасибо за помощь, дальше я бы так и искал ошибку вообще не в этом месте

Comment: и да, огромное спасибо, что напомнили про while, уже потихоньку начинаю себя отучать

Comment: циклы for, foreach, while стоит освоить.